# map into an array of object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I've got that object :

```
foodDatas: {
  "_id": "603cf063c9f3a13528634bab",
  "description": "petit déjeuner parisien local sur l'ile",
  "hotel": "603cd6ae5206ad4f04296218",
  "nameArticle": "Parisien",
  "prix": 15,
  "type": "PetitDejeuner",
  "detail": [
    { "pastries": ["croissant","pain au chocolat"] },
    { "drinks": ["café","thé"] },
    { "fromages": ["kiri", "camembert"] },
  ],
  
}
```

What I want to do is to map through **detail** array to display each element of the value of the objects that contains each of its elements.

In others terms, I want to make a list like below

pastries:

- croissant
- pain au chocolat

drinks:

- café
- thé

fromages:

- kiri
- camemebert

I've tried this :

```
                    {Object.keys(foodDatas.detail).map((category, i) => {
                      
                      return (
                        <>
                        <Text style={styles.category}>{category}</Text>
                        
// From here I want to map through category to display its content** 

                        <View style={styles.choices}>
                          <View style={styles.options}>
                            <TextInput
                              style={styles.input}
                              onChangeText={handleChange("croissant")}
                              placeholder={"1"}
                              keyboardType={'numeric'}
                              value={values.croissant}
         
                            />
                         
                            <Text style={styles.itemOption}>Croissant</Text>
                          </View>
                          </View>
                        </>
                      )
                    })}
```

But I didn't get the name of the categories (pastries, fromages, etc.), instead I've got their index (0,1, etc.). Also, I don't know how to retrieve the value of each category ( croissant, pain au chocolat, café, etc.)

Thank for any help you can give

Comment: Note if you are responsible for the data structure, it is far better to use a common key name structure in each object such as `{type:'pastries, items:["croissant","pain au chocolat"]}` rather than using unique key names generated by the category names

Answer (score 2):

To first address why you're getting the index, it's because you're using Object.keys() on an array (foodDatas.detail is an array not an object).

To get your current implementation working, you'll need to do something like:

```
return foodDatas.detail.map((categoryObj) => (
    Object.keys(categoryObj).map((category) => (
        <>
            <Text style={styles.category}>{category}</Text>
            {categoryObj[category].map((entry) => (
                <View style={styles.choices}>
                    <View style={styles.options}>
                        <TextInput
                          style={styles.input}
                          onChangeText={handleChange(entry)}
                          placeholder={"1"}
                          keyboardType={'numeric'}
                          value={entry}
                        />
                        <Text style={styles.itemOption}>{entry}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            ))}
        </>
    
    ));
));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to iterate over `foodDatas.detail` using Object.keys(foodDatas.detail) it will return index because `foodDatas.detail` is an array and the key are the indexes.

```js
// If you check in your debugger/Console this is the structure
detail: [
  0: {pastries: Array(2)}
  1: {drinks: Array(2)}
  2: {fromages: Array(2)}
]
```

This is not solution but will make you understand a bit, probably you will need 2 loops to achieve what you want.

```js
foodDatas.detail.map((category, i)=>{
    // This will give each object { "pastries": ["croissant","pain au chocolat"] }
    const [key] = Object.keys(category); // key will be pastries, drinks, fromages, etc
    const value = Object.values(category); // value will be ["croissant","pain au chocolat"], ["café","thé"], ["kiri", "camembert"]

    console.log(key, value); // You can verify it here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Code looks something like this

```
const foodDatas = {
      "_id": "603cf063c9f3a13528634bab",
      "description": "petit déjeuner parisien local sur l'ile",
      "hotel": "603cd6ae5206ad4f04296218",
      "nameArticle": "Parisien",
      "prix": 15,
      "type": "PetitDejeuner",
      "detail": [
        { "pastries": ["croissant","pain au chocolat"] },
        { "drinks": ["café","thé"] },
        { "fromages": ["kiri", "camembert"] },
      ],
    };


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        {foodDatas["detail"].map((item, key) =>
        Object.keys(item).map((key) => (
          <div>
            {key}
            <ul>
              {item[key].map((subitem , key) => (
                <li>{subitem}</li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))
      )}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like this:

```js
const foodDatas = {
  _id: "603cf063c9f3a13528634bab",
  description: "petit déjeuner parisien local sur l'ile",
  hotel: "603cd6ae5206ad4f04296218",
  nameArticle: "Parisien",
  prix: 15,
  type: "PetitDejeuner",
  detail: [
    { pastries: ["croissant", "pain au chocolat"] },
    { drinks: ["café", "thé"] },
    { fromages: ["kiri", "camembert"] },
  ],
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {foodDatas["detail"].map((object, key) =>
        Object.keys(object).map((key) => (
          <ul>
            {key}
            {object[key].map((element) => (
              <li>{element}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```